# Laravel - How can I successfully upload files to S3 using a generated pre-signed URL with Laravel's HTTP facade?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-8, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload files of type 'UploadedFile' to an AWS S3 bucket using a pre-signed URL but I'm having issues getting the file to upload correctly without being corrupted. I can get the file uploaded to the S3 bucket just fine, but when I download the file directly from the AWS bucket, the file is corrupted. I noticed that when the file gets uploaded to the S3 bucket, it is larger in size than the original file is from my computer. I think the reason for this is my use of `mb_convert_encoding()` around the contents of the file. If I don't use `mb_convert_encoding()` I get a JSON error when trying to upload telling me `json_encode error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`

Here is what I've tried:

```
function presignedUpload($file)
{
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $key = $fileName;
    $expiration = '+10 minutes';
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
    $adapter = $s3->getDriver()->getAdapter();

    if ($adapter instanceof CachedAdapter)
    {
        $decoratedAdapter = $adapter->getAdapter();
        $client = $decoratedAdapter->getClient();

        $command = $client->getCommand('PutObject', [
            'Bucket' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
            'Key' => $key,
        ]);

        $presignedUrl = (string) $client->createPresignedRequest($command, $expiration)->getUri();

        Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
        ])->put($presignedUrl, mb_convert_encoding($fileContent, 'UTF-8', 'auto'));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what else I might be able to try?

Comment: Welcome. What type of file are you trying to upload? Is it a PDF of some sort since you have `octet-stream`?